# iPhone is unable to import photo on SD card that are copied from macOS

Tags: macos, ios, photos, sd-card

I have copied a bunch of photo files (jpg) from a macOS to a SD card.

[image]

Here is the details of the SD card as seen in Disk Utility

[image]

However when I insert this card to a SD card reader connected to an iOS device, the Photo app shows 'No Photos to import'.

[image]

If the SD card is directly taken out from a mirrorless camera, I can use the SD card to import the photos in it with no issue.

I have already tried reformat the SD card with Disk Utility and copied the files over again. It only makes the situration worse: Photo does not even show the 'Import' tab.

So why this happens, and how can I fix this? I want to be able to import some photo via my iOS device.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is supported in iOS 13. I think it might be supported in iOS 14 though.